# Why My PHP code INSERT Command is inserting duplicate data sometimes?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is My Code. Its all working fine. But Some Times it inserting Duplicate Data. Why?  I mean i placed the code so that same `quize_no` and `phone` combination should not submitted. But Some time its Inserting the Same `quize_no` and `phone` combination. Why is this Happening?

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_mm WHERE phone='$phone'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
}

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$time = date('h:i:s a', time());

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM score_mm WHERE phone='$phone' AND quize_no='$quize_no' ");

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count>0)
{
    echo "1";
}
else
{
    // Here I am Inserting Value in to Database
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into score_mm(name, phone, quize_no, score, date, time) values ('$name', '$phone','$quize_no', '$score', '$date', '$time')");
    echo "Score Submitted Succesfully";
    mysqli_close($con); 
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? The code indeed does look fine, but can you hsow us the check on forhand. The checks would help, so we can figure out what is wrong. Are your inserted values really idenitcal or are there spaces in it? 'cause in that case you need to remove those spaces for example ot make it match in your code,

Comment: Off topic, but never ever blindly insert variables into your SQL string unless you want to risk SQL injection. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: plus they need to be sanitized as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If there should truly never be a situation where you end up with duplicate `quize_no` and `phone` combinations in that table, then the first thing you should do is change your table structure to add a unique key to those columns.

For example:
`ALTER TABLE score_mm ADD UNIQUE (quize_no, phone);`

This won't fix whatever is causing multiple insert requests to be called, but it would at least protect your data integrity by not allowing any rows with duplicate value combinations.